# mysql too many connection error.

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a `.txt` file with a list of 60,000 English words. I wanted to insert those to my database, so I simply just did as show here.

```
$file = new SplFileObject('list.txt');

foreach ($file as $line => $word) {
    $p = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=test_dictionary', 'root', 'test');
    $p->query("INSERT INTO words (english) VALUES('$word') ");
}
```

Now, after I run this script, I get the following error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1040] Too many connections' in /var/www/skillz/test/curl/index.php:17 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/test/index.php(17): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', 'test') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/test/index.php on line 4`

That `line 4` is where the `new PDO('mysql:')` is located. So, I tried to search this error, and found [this answer that seemed a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040048/php-mysql-too-many-connections-to-database-error). And I edited mysql accordingly, as

```
$ vi /etc/my.cnf
  max_connections=250
```

But I still get the same error, I have `MySql 5.5.38` running PHP-FPM, NGINX in CentOS 6.5

Comment: solved! Sorry. It worked when I moved PDO from the loop. such a silly mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't open a new Connection for every word. You only need one connection open for the lifetime of your inserts. I'm not sure about the true lifetime of a PDO object, I know they're cleaned up when they're not used, but garbage collection might not do that for a couple of minutes, and for 60,000 words, you're going to hit your limit of connections to the database faster than it can clean them up.

```
$file = new SplFileObject('list.txt');
$p = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=test_dictionary', 'root', 'test');

foreach ($file as $line => $word) {

    $p->query("INSERT INTO words (english) VALUES('$word') ");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should declare the SQL connection outside the foreach.
Because it will make 60.000 connections.

```
$file = new SplFileObject('list.txt');
$p = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=test_dictionary', 'root', 'test');

foreach ($file as $line => $word) {

    $p->query("INSERT INTO words (english) VALUES('$word') ");
}
```

You only need to declare the SQL connection once and you can use it anytime as you want.
If you put it in foreach it will make a SQL connection every word, that's why you got that message.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1**
Use batch insert statement :

```
INSERT INTO words (col1, col2) VALUES ('val1', 'val2'), ('val3', 'val4'), ...('val3n', 'val4n');
```

This fails if you also want to check if some rows failed or not. So, below is another solution.

**Solution 2**

Create a persistent database connection. This will use the same connection in all iterations of the loop.

```
$file = new SplFileObject('list.txt');
$p = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=test_dictionary', 'root', 'test', array(
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true)); //Persistent Database Connection
foreach ($file as $line => $word) {
    $p->query("INSERT INTO words (english) VALUES('$word') ");
}
$p = null; //Destroy Connection
```

Comment: For 60,000 entries I wouldn't want to try and take a look at that SQL if it failed to insert one.

Comment: Hey @Hammerstein, I've made an edit to the answer. You can use `sleep` command to force the connection to be re-used.

Comment: Not very effective, but +1 for the effort. Because, `sleep(1)` would delay each iteration by 1 second, it would almost take 60,000 seconds to complete the query

Comment: Hey @Hammerstein, I've made another edit. Solution 2 is perfect for you. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: I wasn't the one looking to insert 60,000 words. But, yes we all agreed that opening a single connection for the duration of the 60,000 was a good idea. Although, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332074/what-are-the-disadvantages-of-using-persistent-connection-in-pdo it's an interesting answer to using persistent connection in PDO.