# Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: (08004/1040): Too many connections in OpenCart

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, opencart

Guys i am having errors in my opencart website, but actually the problem is that this error also displays my database login and password. How can i fix this problem.

The error raised is like

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception "ErrorException" with message "Error: Could not make a database link (1040) Too many connections" in /home/*******/public_html/system/database/mysqli.php:9 Stack trace: #0 /home//*******//public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_library_db.php(13): DBMySQLi->__construct("localhost", "/*******/", "/*******/", "*******") #1 /home/******/public_html/index.php(46): DB->__construct("mysqli", "localhost", "/*******/", "/*******/", "/*******/") #2 {main} thrown in /home/*******/public_html/system/database/mysqli.php on line 9
```

OpenCart Version 1.5.6.1

Comment: Make sure you are closing the connections that you open. Also if there is high concurrency increase the max connections in my.ini file.

Comment: Restarting mysql service will temporarily solve your problem

Comment: Which version of opencart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address the most pressing issue: in production environments you should turn off error reporting.

There are some configuration settings you need to look into:

`error_reporting`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

`display_errors`: http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors

For safety's sake, you should probably change your database password as well. Even if no one has seen it, it's not worth the risk.

There are numerous questions on SO about the too many connections issue. Here's one quite well upvoted answer: [php, mysql - Too many connections to database error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040048/php-mysql-too-many-connections-to-database-error)

Comment: And then just ignore the error?

Comment: @wumm primary issue: stop your production DB password being visible. As for too many connections, I am getting to that but it has also been addressed in the comments above. Hardly worthy of a downvote, it answers an aspect of the question.